# How do you split data from a textfile on an array list?

Tags: arraylist, split

I am trying to code an array list that contains information from a text file that should add all the characters of the names together to give me a total. I have done it but it adds the spaces to, i have tried using .split(" "); but it still didnt work.
here is my code so far

```
    String tempLatinName = " ";
    String latinLength = " ";
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
        tempLatinName = info.get(i).getLatinName();   
        tempLatinName.split(" ");
        latinLength = tempLatinName;
        letters += latinLength.length();
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of letters in all Latin names = " + letters);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: you may need to use trim() as well.

Comment: i tried trim, it didnt work since the words in the text file are 2 words but .replace worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number of characters in your string, instead of `tempLatinName.split(" ");` you should try `latinLength = tempLatinName.replace(" ","");` and then you would get the length with the string without spaces with `latinLength.Length`
 More about replace [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) 
More about Length [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer is ok with you,  check it as the selected answer please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

based from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

have you tried the following:

> tempLatinName.split(' ');

or

> tempLatinName.split();